# Метод offsetChange не возвращает значение xPixelOffset на некоторых устройствах

Tags: java, libgdx, livewallpaper

Приложение представляет собой простые LiveWallpapers, написанные с помощью LibGdx. Метод `offsetChange` отвечает за смещение фона живых обоев, а переменная `xPixelOffset` принимает значение от 0 до 1. Например, если на устройстве 3 рабочих стола, то при пролистывании обоев переменная   `xPixelOffset` принимает значение 0, 0.5, 1 на каждом рабочем столе соответственно. Проблема в том, что данный алгоритм работает не на всех устройствах. На Sony Xperia M (API 18) работает без нареканий. На Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (API 17) и HTC Desire 601 (API 17) - вышеупомянутый алгоритм не работает и при пролистывании обоев фон рабочего стола остаётся неподвижным. 
Код прилагаю:
AndroidLauncher.java

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidLiveWallpaperService {
    public static float pixeloffset = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreateApplication () {
        super.onCreateApplication();

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.useCompass = false;
        config.useWakelock = false;
        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        config.getTouchEventsForLiveWallpaper = true;

        final ApplicationListener listener = new MyLiveWallpaperListener();
        initialize(listener, config);
    }

    public class MyLiveWallpaperListener extends MyWallpaper implements AndroidWallpaperListener{

        @Override
        public void create() {
            super.resolver = new Resolver() {

                @Override
                public float getxPixelOffset() {
                    return pixeloffset;
                }
            };
            super.create();
        };

        @Override
        public void offsetChange(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {
            pixeloffset = xPixelOffset;
        }

        @Override
        public void previewStateChange(boolean isPreview) {
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу помощи в разъяснении причин столь странной работы данного метода, а также пути возможной его замены.

Comment: did you get the answer ? I am facing the same problem